# How to add a horizontal line between top text and bottom date inline in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

how to add a horizontal line between top text and bottom date in MS word like attached picture. In the picture I could not add words before and front of horizontal line because I have made that with using cells of table.[image: horizontal line]

Comment: You need to post the file.

Comment: You need to give/show more details about the texts around where you want to put the line.

Comment: for example: My letter No is 2048/3-Oct-2023 and continue rest of words. i wanted to use (inline and everywhere when i want to refer a letter no in my ms word file.

Comment: Use the formula editor.

Comment: can you explain how with sample?

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igz7B.png)?

Comment: yes, exactly.!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easily accomplished using Word's built in equation editor.

1. Insert > Symbols > Equation > Insert New Equation
2. Select Structures > Fraction > Stacked Fraction
   [image: insert fraction]
3. Select each box in the fraction and enter your values.
   [image: final equation]
4. Format to taste. The equation text can be formatted (e.g. red, bold in the screenshot) like any other Word text (color, font, size, bold, etc...).  Using the equation dropdown, you can also select an in-line option.

Once you're finished, you can select the fraction drop down and save it as a new equation for reuse.  For the example, I've named it su_1794568 and its visible towards the bottom of the list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, after saving as a new equation i cannot find that. can i put a shortcut as a normal equation for that.?

Comment: I'm not sure.  When I saved my test equation, I was able to find it in: _insert > symbols > equation > built-in_ and also _insert > text > quick part > building blocks organizer > equations gallery_

Answer (score 2):

On the Ribbon bar in Word, go to Insert > Equation (or type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>). On the Equation bar, choose Fraction > Stacked Fraction (top left)

[image]

Put your cursor in the box at the top and type the first part of the equation.

[image]

Then move the cursor to the bottom box and enter the other part of the equation.

[image]

You can then type in front of, after, above, below, over the top of the equation; whichever you prefer.